# Send multiple outputs to sed

Tags: linux, bash

When there is a program which, upon execution, prints several lines on `stout`, how can I redirect all those lines to `sed` and perform some operations on them while they are being generated?

For example:

```
7zip a -t7z output_folder input_folder -mx9 > sed 's/.*[ \t][ \t]*\([0-9][0-9]*\)%.*/\1/'
```

7zip generates a series of lines as output, each including a percentage value, and I would like `sed` to display these values only, while they are being generated. The above script unfortunately does not work...

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should pipe it using `|` instead of redirecting to `sed` file. Also, consider using `grep`.

Comment: Would grep give some advantages?

Comment: it just can help you to simplify the re you use. You can grep what you want and display the results only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the pipe `|` instead of redirection `>` so that `sed` uses first command output as its input.

The above script line must have created a `sed` file in the current directory.

Furthermore, maybe `7zip` outputs these lines to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. If it is the case, first redirect standard error to standard output before piping: `2>&1 |`